# Finding "fallthroughs" in C code

Tags: c, switch-statement, static-analysis

There were several nasty bugs discovered in a product I am working on, all related to inadvertent "fall throughs" in switch statements.

Now, I would like to go one step beyond - I would like to detect switch statement fall throughs in a large body of C code. **I can use only Linux and gcc 5.6 for compilation** (so no clang or newer gcc; this is because newer gcc does not exist for the target architecture for our project).

This is a code without fall through:

```
    switch(m_loadAnimSubCt){
        case 0: 
        case 1: 
            // Do something
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            // Do something
            break;
   }
```

This is a code with fall throughs:

```js
   switch(m_loadAnimSubCt){
        case 0: 
        case 1: 
            // Do something but fall through to the other cases 
            // after doing it.
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            // Do something else.
            break;
   }
```

Comment: You should probably research the terms *statical analysis* and *linter*.

Comment: I did, and it looks fallthroughs are seldom covered. I know that there is a switch in the newest gcc for that, but I can't use that version of gcc.

Comment: Both of your examples have "fall throughs" - case `0` falls through to case `1`.    In any event, if you want to detect such things, write a bit of code that parses your source file, and screams if the conditions you want are not met.   A C compiler won't normally diagnose such things, since the code is valid - so you write code to do it yourself.

Comment: @Peter, it depends on the definition. For me, the first example uses multiple cases to handle them in the same way. But, this is splitting a hair. It is clear what I meant to a reasonable reader I think.

Comment: That's weird, I haven't found any statical analysis tools that *doesn't* covers this. It's been part of linters for C basically since they were invented. That's why it used to be common to have comments like `/*FALLTRHOUGH*/` in cases where fallthrough was expected, so the linter could check for that. I mostly use [clang-analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) these days, haven't checked if it's enabled by default there but I'm sure it must exist a switch for it.

Comment: "Statical" is not a word. It's just "static".

Comment: You might write a GCC plugin (or a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension) to do the additional checks you want.

Comment: As a variant, you can try using PVS-Studio code analyzer. It'll be able to check a project, build with the help of gcc 5.4. In the analyzer there is a number of diagnostics, meant to detect bugs, related to using switch operator: [V622](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V622/), [V719](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V719/), [V785](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V785/), [V796](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V796/). I think, V796 will help you.

Comment: @VividD: please mention your weird target architecture in the question. I'm surprised a newer `gcc` don't exist

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If I told you the target architecture, I would have to kill you, and all readers of this question as well. ;)

Comment: I don't think so. You apparently are using some old variant of a free software compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You are obviously not aware of the amount of efforts that must be invested in producing a new version of gcc for a particular architecture. Intel, arm - this will be supported, but other architectures always lag. It looks the prevailing perception is that all is just automatic, but this is very far from the truth.

Comment: I am aware of that since I am an occasional GCC contributor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using GCC, you should use the [`Wimplicit-fallthrough` compiler option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-fallthrough) to generate a warning for fallthroughs. You can alternatively make it into an error using `-Werror` (i.e. `-Werror=implicit-fallthrough` for this specific warning.

I would prefer using `-Wextra` (which includes this and many other additional warnings), but if this is some large legacy codebase, it might generate too much noise. It *is* what you should strive for, to pass the build with `-Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror`.

If your compiler version doesn't support such option, perhaps you can write your own regex which would match all `case`s not prefixed by a previous `case` statement, although you would have to be careful to ensure that the regex matches all occurrences, regardless of formatting/comments.

For example, you could use something like this (here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/caQ5aD/1)):

```regex
(?# match any 'case' following 'break;', ':' or '{' into a non-capturing group)
(?# then match the remaining 'case' into a named "fallthrough" group)
(?:(break;|:|{)[\r\n\s]*case) | (?<fallthrough>case)
```

So you can run a perl (or python, or whatever) script against your folder and dump all lines where the "fallthrough" group is captured.

Comment: Good, but that `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`  is only in recent version of GCC

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you're right, I noticed OP is using gcc 5.4. I suppose a regex *might* do the trick, I'll update the answer when I get a spare moment.

Comment: I upgraded the gcc, so I am going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest compiling your code with a newer compiler just to detect those (I know you mentioned you could not do that for the project but it's sometimes useful to compile it with something else to have a different perspective on things).

What we have at my work is an (scarily) old version of GCC compiling our "official" code and clang doing a dummy compilation just to have better static analysis.

Comment: This is a quite reasonable suggestion too, a dummy compilation with a newer compiler would serve as an external linter.

Comment: A newer gcc does not exist for my target architecture. 5.6 is the newest. @Groo

Comment: @VividD you don't need to compile for your target architecture that's the point, since you only need the linting information given by the compiler